# Extracting data from file to file in Python

Tags: python, extract

I would like to extract data from first file to second file and put them into specific labels.
The first file looks like:

```
"city1" : [[1.1,1.2],[2.1,2.2],[3.1,3.2]],
"city2" : [[5.0,0.2],[4.1,3.2],[7.1,8.2]],
...
```

So type is like dictionary where values are list of lists

Unfortunately while opening file I got error: ***too many values to unpack***

Im trying to open like:

```
lines = {}
with open("shape.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f:
    (key,val) = line.split()
    d[key] = val
```

After that I would like to extract this cities and coordinates to second file which has structure like this:

```
<state name = 'city1'>
 <point lat='first value from first list', lng='second value from first list/>
 <point lat='first value from second list', lng='second value from second list/>
</state>
<state name = 'city2'>
 the same action like above
```

And I was thinking if there is a other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text file contains only this structure you have stated in question, you should be able to use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the data:

```
txt = '''

"city1" : [[1.1,1.2],[2.1,2.2],[3.1,3.2]],
"city2" : [[5.0,0.2],[4.1,3.2],[7.1,8.2]],

'''

template = '''<state name = '{city}'>
  <point lat='{vals[0][0]}', lng='{vals[0][1]}' />
  <point lat='{vals[1][0]}', lng='{vals[1][1]}' />
</state>'''

from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval('{' + txt + '}')

print(data)

for k, v in data.items():
    print(template.format(city=k, vals=v))
```

Prints:

```
<state name = 'city1'>
  <point lat='1.1', lng='1.2' />
  <point lat='2.1', lng='2.2' />
</state>
<state name = 'city2'>
  <point lat='5.0', lng='0.2' />
  <point lat='4.1', lng='3.2' />
</state>
```

---

With files I/O:

```
template = '''<state name = '{city}'>
  <point lat='{vals[0][0]}', lng='{vals[0][1]}' />
  <point lat='{vals[1][0]}', lng='{vals[1][1]}' />
</state>'''

from ast import literal_eval

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('sample.out', 'w') as f_out:
    data = literal_eval('{' + f_in.read() + '}')

    for k, v in data.items():
        print(template.format(city=k, vals=v), file=f_out)
```

---

EDIT: This example will print all the points to the file:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('sample.out', 'w') as f_out:
    data = literal_eval('{' + f_in.read() + '}')

    for k, v in data.items():
        print("<state name = '{city}'>".format(city=k), file=f_out)
        for point in v:
            print("\t<point lat='{point[0]}', lng='{point[1]}' />".format(point=point), file=f_out)
        print('</state>', file=f_out)
```

The file `sample.out` will look like:

```
<state name = 'city1'>
    <point lat='1.1', lng='1.2' />
    <point lat='2.1', lng='2.2' />
    <point lat='3.1', lng='3.2' />
</state>
<state name = 'city2'>
    <point lat='5.0', lng='0.2' />
    <point lat='4.1', lng='3.2' />
    <point lat='7.1', lng='8.2' />
</state>
```

Comment: Okey, but I cant point every coord in code, because there is huge amount of coords in text file, so <point lat='{vals[1][0]}', lng='{vals[1][1]}' /> would not be efficient

Comment: Woah, didn't know about literal_eval. It's nice.

Comment: @Frendom I don't understand. `{vals[1][0]}` is only text formatting variable. The input text file is parsed as dictionary with keys as cities and values as 3-element lists. So `vals` in this case is each time list of 3 elements.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I think he meant that there's a lot more than two point per city

Comment: @PaulShishmarev Main goal is to create shape of map for each area in file: Each area has huge amount of cords (X,Y) who are stored in list of lists. I found a method to draw area based on coords, but I need specific structure to move data from first file to the second file

Comment: @AndrejKesely this solution works fine, I got the file with correct template, but only get 2 points, but in the file there is much more points. I should use loop to fix it, but really dont know how to construct it in this case

Comment: @Frendom I've updated my answer - should be now OK.

Comment: You shouldn't load the whole file into `dict` if you want only extract to another file.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily load and save lists and dictionaries with it.

```
import json

data = {
  'city1': [[1.1,1.2],[2.1,2.2],[3.1,3.2]],
  'city2': [[5.0,0.2],[4.1,3.2],[7.1,8.2]],
}

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(json.dumps(data))

with open('file.txt') as f:
   data = json.loads(f.read())
```

But it will work only if file has valid json.
You file is almost valid JSON except that it does not have curly braces

So I think it can be done like this:

```
lines = ['{']
with open('file') as f:
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
lines[-1].strip(',')  # Strip last comma as it's not valid for JSON dict
lines.append('}')
data = json.loads('\n'.join(lines))
```

Then just do:

```
result = ''
for city, points in data.items():
    result += f"<state name='{city}'>\n"
    for point in points:
        result += f"<point lat='{point[0]}', lng='{point[1]}'/>\n"
    result += '</state>\n'

 with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way which writes directly to the second file. This way you do not need to store it `dict` first. Much more performant if you handle some big file:

```
with open("shape.txt", "r") as f1:
    with open("shape_output.txt", "w") as f2:
        for line in f1:
            (key, val) = line.split(":")
            coord = json.loads(val.strip().rstrip(','))
            city = key.replace('"', '').strip()

            new_line = f"<state name = '{city}'>"
            for c in coord:
                new_line += f"<point lat='{c[0]}', lng='{c[1]}'/>"
            new_line += "</state>"

            f2.write(new_line)
            f2.write("\n")
```

I add some cleaning when reading lines from the first file. And then use `json.loads` to convert the array from the string format to array type.

The rest is just formating and writing to the second file.